# MassTransit generic consumer doesn't consume

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, messagebroker

I'm ussing MassTransit 3 with RabbitMQ.

I changed the classic example on the web site:

this:

```
x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceQueueName"],
    e => { e.Consumer<RequestConsumer>(); });
```

with

```
            var consumer = new RequestConsumerT<string, string>(request =>
                {
                    return "here it is " + request;
                }
            );
            x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceQueueName"],
                e => { e.Instance(consumer); });
```

and I'm using the RequestConsumerT class as the consumer:

```
public class RequestConsumerT<TRequest, TResponse> :
    IConsumer<TRequest>
    where TRequest: class
    where TResponse : class
{
    Func<TRequest, TResponse> _implementation;

    public RequestConsumerT(Func<TRequest, TResponse> implementation)
    {
        _implementation = implementation;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TRequest> context)
    {
        //await context.RespondAsync<TResponse>(_implementation.Invoke(context.Message));
        context.Respond<TResponse>(_implementation.Invoke(context.Message));
    }
```

Then, when I make a request the consumer is not answering.
what is wrong with my code, please?

Thank you

## UPDATE:

This is the error I get:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: b8ea0000-d435-8cdc-039a-08d3f41435b2
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.MessageRequestClient`2.<Request>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Evolve.Messaging.Brokers.MassRabbitConnection.<>c__DisplayClass10`2.<<Request>b__d>d__12.MoveNext() in g:\src\Evolve.Messaging\Evolve.Messaging\Brokers\MassRabbitConnection.cs:line 198
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Evolve.Messaging.Brokers.MassRabbitConnection.Request[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, String serviceName) in g:\src\Evolve.Messaging\Evolve.Messaging\Brokers\MassRabbitConnection.cs:line 203
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in g:\src\Evolve.Messaging\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 47
---> (Inner Exception #0) MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: b8ea0000-d435-8cdc-039a-08d3f41435b2
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.MessageRequestClient`2.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Evolve.Messaging.Brokers.MassRabbitConnection.<>c__DisplayClass10`2.<b__d>d__12.MoveNext() in g:\src\Evolve.Messaging\Evolve.Messaging\Brokers\MassRabbitConnection.cs:line 198<---

and here some Rabbitmq manager screenshots:

[The consumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQTnX.png)

[Exchanges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pFlc.png)

Comment: String is not a valid message type. Create a class or interface for your message and try again.

Comment: @Chris, Thank you for your answer, my compliments for your good and hard work and thank you again for sharing your knowledge and your work.

Comment: @Chris, I'm trying to create an abstraction over MassTransit, the examples in the docs works fine but with my generic implementation doesn't works out, I'm trying to find the cause, thank you again

Comment: Good luck, creating an abstraction is hard, but it can be done. I created an example way to do it here if you need some input on how to do it: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/MassTransit.Tests/Conventional

Comment: @Chris Patterson, I'll check that, Thank you again